# add_filter OO with parameters

Tags: plugin-development, filters, actions

How to use Oriented Object concept in `add_filter` or `add_action` with priority and number of parameters?

This is possible without additional parameters:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', array($this, 'useCDN');
```

With parameters this is possible? How to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's done the same way you would do in procedural, you need to provide the `priority` and the `number of parameters`

so you would have;

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', array($this, 'useCDN'), 10, 3);
```

to pass 3 additional parameters to the filter